# google sitemap protocol - how create sitemap in asp.net 4 for google

Tags: asp.net, navigation, protocols, xml-sitemap

hi my dear lords :
i have a page like below :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MySiteNav.aspx.cs" Inherits="Amlak.MySiteNav" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Site Nav</title>
    <link href="Styles/MySiteNav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h3>
    My Web Site Navigation
    </h3>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
        </asp:TreeView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Q's :
1-is it enough for introduce to google as my web site navigation site map?
should i add something in this page or other pages?

2-what is the regular protocol for google SiteMap ?
i googled it for this protocol ! but i seems this protocol has been deleted from google help! the other resources are too old!

thanks for halp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information about Google's accepted Sitemap protocol can be found from the following page:

> [About Sitemaps](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156184&hl=en) on the Webmaster Tools Help site.

They also provide details on [How to create a Sitemap](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183668).

Note that this is a different format to that chosen by MS for the ASP.NET Sitemap format, but you might well be able to produce one from the other with some XSLT - for example, the search engine Sitemap doesn't really care about site structure because it's not building navigational features, it only cares about the pages themselves.

---

**Edit to respond to comment:**

Once you've created your sitemap you need to tell the search engines about it. There are a number of ways you can do this, starting with the page linked to from my second link called ["Submitting Sitemaps"](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183669).

Many site engines also support the "Sitemap" extension to the [`Robots.txt` file](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html):

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_location.xml
```

Another option is to add it to the metadata of one or more of your pages:

```
<link rel="sitemap" href="sitemap.xml" type="application/xml" />
```

Alternatively, if you're not being crawled well at the moment, you can also submitting it directly to the search engines using their Webmasters areas, where you can log in, and once you've proved ownership of the site (usually by uploading a "known" file to the root, or modifying the metadata of the homepage with a known string), you are able to upload sitemaps directly, manage URLs, and get reports on performance:

- [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/)
- [Bing Webmaster Tools](http://www.bing.com/webmaster)
- [Yahoo Site Explorer](https://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com)
- Etc.

Comment: thanks for answer / but after making that xml file what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

here is some information on what format you'd need to have for your sitemap: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.vinull.com/Post/2006/12/03/aspnet-supporting-the-sitemap-protocol.aspx for integrating asp.net `SiteMapProviders` with the sitemaps protocol.

Comment: thank you man / but it has error in this line in .net 4.0 -> foreach (SiteMapNode node in SiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNode("~/Default.aspx").GetAllNodes()) !!!

Comment: So, what is the error? Make sure you add using System.Web at the top.